# Passing variables through blade includes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm a beginner in Laravel and I'm getting practices converting a previous (simple) website to Laravel.

Basically, I created a template having HTML structure and I change the main content using **@includes** and **@yield**

The interesting parts in html ***template.blade.php*** are like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
<!-- Title -->
<title>@yield('title')</title>

....
....

<!-- CSS Customization -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/custom.css">
@yield('css')

....
....

@include('include._header')
@include('include._test_script')
@include('include._footer')

....
....

<!-- JS Customization -->
<script src="/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
@yield('js')
```

The router calls the ***test.blade.php*** which include the template. This blade file has some custom php code having the **$extra_script** variable

```
<?php $extra_script = " alert(0); console.log(0);";?>

@extends('layouts.template')

@section('css')
   ....
@endsection

@section('js')
    ...
    <script>
        {!! $extra_script !!}
    </script>
@endsection
```

Loading this page the script works fine and I see the alert message having the 0 content.

Now I'm trying to update the **$extra_string** into the ***/include/test_script.blade.php*** file but it doesn't work.

This include blade file is like:

```
 @php
     $extra_script = " alert(1); console.log(1);";
 @endphp

 or

 <?php $extra_script = " alert(1); console.log(1);"; ?>
```

The result is no errors and still alert(0) shown.

I understand is not elegant to have PHP code in the blade template but in the controller but this is a quick and fast porting to have the website online in a few time.

How to fix it in view?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the order is incorrect, first `test.blade.php` is extending from `template.blade.php`. It is `template.blade.php` the one setting the alert to 1 by `@include('include._extra_script')` but then as `test.blade.php` is extending from that template, it is overwriting `$extra_script` to the one that alerts a 0.